# how to show data in grid/thumbnails

Tags: html, jsp

How to show data from database in grid/thumbnails [like this](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/browse/opening/?minTomato=0&maxTomato=100&minPopcorn=0&maxPopcorn=100&services=&genres=1;2;4;5;6;8;9;10;11;13;14;18&sortBy=popularity&certified=false&adid=home_list1all) Or something like this
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmpm/ygreepk3/). I am using spring/jsp technologies. Right now i am showing it in a table like this.

In JSP

```
<table class="pdtTable"  border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>       
    </tr>
   <c:forEach items="${productList}" var="product" >
    <tr>
        <td><a href="details${product.id}"> ${product.productName}</a></td>
        </tr>    
   </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`varStatus`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) attribute in your `forEach` loop and use it to check (using the modulo operator) if you need to start or close a row.

```
<table class="pdtTable"  border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th>Product Name</th>       
  </tr>
  <c:forEach items="${productList}" var="product" varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="${status.index % 3 == 0}"><tr></c:if>
    <td><a href="details${product.id}"> ${product.productName}</a></td>
    <c:if test="${status.index % 3 == 2}"></tr></c:if>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

This can leave your table row unclosed, so you need to build a check for that.

A better solution would be using [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info) and syle a list of items using float for example:

```css
ul.tiles { width: 400px; }
ul.tiles li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tiles">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Okay i will try now. Can i use any jquery plugin to generate this?

Comment: jQuery (or plain JavaScript) can't be used to generate JSP.

Comment: I know some CSS and jquery.To show like in that site, its just enough to use jsp and css?

Comment: See the CSS example I've added.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: Yeah got it. Sorry for that comment.

Comment: Okay thanks. I am gonna accept your answer. Is there a way to chat with you in private.

Comment: You could use Twitter or ask new questions here.